# how to make a form tag disappear after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make this form tag disappear after i hit the submit button.
I tried using "formaction" but it doesn't let me add my data to database. I am thinking of using JavaScript but have no idea how to make this form disappear.

```
<form id ='eventdetail' name='eventform' method='POST' action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?month=<?php echo $month;?>&day=<?php echo $day;?>&year=<?php echo $year; ?>&v=true&add=true">
    <table width='400px' border='0'>
        <tr>
            <td width='150px'>Date</td>
            <td width='250px'><input type='text' name='txttitle' value ='<?php echo $month?>/<?php echo $day?>/<?php echo $year?>'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='150px'>Title</td>
            <td width='250px'><input type='text' name='txttitle'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='150px'>Detail</td>
            <td width='250px'><textarea name='txtdetail'></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' align='center'><input type='submit' name='btnadd' value='Add Event'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: once you submit the form, a new page will load (or the same page, depending on the action, which to be honest I can't tell what the submit action page is) ... some logic in the PHP would be needed to not output the form, I guess

Comment: want to stay on the same page after clicking the button. I just want to make this specific form tag disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using javaScript you can create an event and than bind it to a submit button,

```
var hideForm = function() {  
  // to hide 
  var form = document.getElementById('eventdetail');
  form.style.display = 'none';
};
```

In your from you can do somthing like that.

```
<input type="submit" name="btnadd" value="Add Event" onclick="hideForm()">
```

Answer (score 0):

On most sites the submit button links to another page (it could be the same page just without the form), you can read more about submit buttons and how they are generally used here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp scroll down to the "The Submit Button" section!

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on the same page without a refresh, you can use AJAX to send the form's data. 
After that, use JavaScript to make your form disappear : the function is *[removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)*.